# Git authentication failure when cloning from git.milosolutions.com (Qt's Raspberry Pi Beginners Guide)

Tags: git, qt

I am trying to compile QT5 for Raspberry PI and I followed the guide in the link. 
https://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide

I am facing a problem in the following step:

```
git clone https://git.milosolutions.com/other/cross-compile-tools.git
```

I get an authentiction failure. I tried to authenticate using the credentials of my https://gitlab.com/ account, but it does not work.

Could any one please guide me to get a **Milo LDAP account**?

Comment: try with: https://github.com/darius-kim/cross-compile-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gitlab repository hosted by some company. It should not be used in the tutorial in the first place. Maybe the access was open at some point, but now it is not.

As @eyllanesc mentioned, you can get the `fixQualifiedLibraryPaths` script from [this github repo](https://github.com/darius-kim/cross-compile-tools).